# interview questions on sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

Hi I recently crashed and burned on a interview question on file editing. Kinda been bugging me. I searched on the forum but did quite get it to go.

The question was:

testfile.txt has the following:

```
     some test text 1
     some test text 2
     some test text 3
```

Change testfile.txt so it can look like this (with out using VI or gedit):

```
     some test text 1
     some more test text
     some test text 2
     some more test text
     some test text 3
     some more test text
```

I have tried to use sed and awk but the text does not come out where it needs to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 'asome more test text' file
```

This will append the text `some more test text` to every line and amend the original file in place.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
some test text 1
some test text 2
some test text 3
```

In awk:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '{print; print "some more test text"}'
some test text 1
some more test text
some test text 2
some more test text
some test text 3
some more test text
```

Answer (score 1):

posting this for the original question for inserting second line to a text file.

here is one way to do it with `sed`

```
$ seq 3 | sed 2iinserted
1
inserted
2
3
```

For inserting text after every line

```
$ seq 3 | sed 1~1ainserted
1
inserted
2
inserted
3
inserted
```

if you don't understand what this is, read some of the tutorials, internet is full of them.

Comment: that wont do it. plus this will not write to the file...

Comment: I'm giving you hints to motivate you to learn more.  The output can be directed to any file.  Here I start with piped input so there is no file to be overwritten. `sed` has `-i` option to in place edit for a given file input.

Comment: @nycjay01 and the leading spaces can be inserted if the first is escaped: `sed '1~1a\          hello world'`

Comment: dev-null, you sir are a savior. Got it going with the following:                                                  sed -i '1~1a\some more test text' testfile.txt

Comment: Note that `2iinserted` works in GNU sed, but not BSD sed, which requires a newline to follow the `i` command.  So in bash, `seq 3 | sed $'2i\\\ninserted'` gets the same results.  Trickier to do in a one-liner without format expansion though. `

Answer (score 0):

Given the output matching against a repeating phrase `some test text`, I think

```
  sed 's/some test text.*/&\nsome more test text/' file
```

will do

```
some test text 1
some more test text
some test text 2
some more test text
some test text 3
some more test text
```

Of course the `&` char in the RHS of the `s`ubstitute command captures all chars matched and inserts them into the output. We add in `\n some more test text` on a new-line and we're good.

Note that non-gnu/linux seds may not recognized `\n` as a newline, in which case (from the cmd-line), you need to use the key combination `Ctrl-V Ctrl-M` to add line breaks to your output. (I've never seen it explained how `^M` is converted in the file to `^J`, but it goes back to the 80s, so go figure).

IHTH

Comment: Did't add the text :-(    arg this feel like a bad itch LOL

Comment: @nycjay01 : If you're saying it didn't work, then update your Q with output of `uname -a ; sed --version`. Or if you mean, didn't save to the file, the `sed -i ...` most likely will work, depending on your version of `sed` and `OS`. Finally, I see I missed a closing `'` char, now added to code above. Good luck.

Comment: Not sure why I got negative points but I hope this helps someone out there. The fix was simple just used the following command:                    `sed -i '1~1a\some more test text' testfile.txt`